# Will this cause an overflow?

Tags: c, string, overflow

I've the following piece of code and I think it can cause an overflow in the readlink() function.

```
pid_t get_pid_from_proc_self()
{
    char buffer[4];
    pid_t pid;

    readlink("/proc/self", buffer, sizeof(buffer));

    sscanf(buffer, "%d",(int *)&pid);

    return pid;
}
```

Since the PID is 4 bytes in Linux, `readlink()` copies 32 bits from "/proc/self" into `target[]`. Then, according to me, an extra byte should be used for `'\0'`, which makes it 5 bytes.

Also, does `readlink()` automatically inserts `'\0'` at the end if string or do I have to specifically assign it to the last byte?

Comment: Thanks for the comment guys! It was VERY difficult to accept one answer. So I just chose the answer of the user who first noticed that sscanf() will overflow. +1 to all though :) It feels good to learn something new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

readlink won't overflow because it doesn't put the '\0' on the end.   But the sscanf will.  You should do this:

You should do this:

```
char buf[5];
ssizet_t len;
...
if ((len = readlink("/proc/self", buf, sizeof(buf)-1)) != -1)
    buf[len] = '\0';
```

Comment: SO the `sscanf()` function will copy the PID+'\0' into the `pid` variable and cause overflow. Am I correct?

Comment: well, sscanf doesn't know that the buffer is only 4 characters long, so it will keep going past the end.

Comment: If I `Nul` terminate the terminate the string in the 5th byte, then `sscanf()` will copy 4 bytes or 5 bytes:PID+'\0'?

Comment: it won't "copy" it, but yes, it will do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

No, it won't cause an overflow.  It'll read in at most `sizeof(buffer)` bytes, and then stop.  It doesn't null-terminate your string, so you will have to do so.  Reading `buffer` before ensuring the last byte is a `\0` will lead to undefined behavior (which is what your `sscanf()` call is doing).

Comment: The question was about `readlink()`.  I added a comment about reading the string before ensuring it was null-terminated to address the `sscanf` issue, though not explicitly.  I'll do that.

Answer (score 2):

Per the examples shown here:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/readlink.html

```
if ((len = readlink("/modules/pass1", buf, sizeof(buf)-1)) != -1)
    buf[len] = '\0';
```

*Edit:*

I wonder about:

> Since the PID is 4 bytes in Linux, readlink() copies 32 bits from "/proc/self" ...

Don't you get back a string version of the PID, not an actual 4-byte integer? Couldn't your value be up to <strike>10 digits?</strike> 5 digits? *(per comment about max proc value being far less than max 4-byte int value - thanks @Karl)*

Comment: Actually, for most common values of `/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max` it's going to be more like a 5 byte string (my max is 32768), but +1 for noticing the difference between string and int.

Comment: @Karl - crap I knew that (once), but I guess my mind is turning to mush with lack of use.  +1 to you for the highly useful comment.

Answer (score 1):

`readlink()` will not cause an overflow, but it will not append the trailing `\0` and `sscanf()` may potentially hurt badly (buffer overflow). From the `readlink()` manpage.

> readlink() places the contents of the
>   symbolic link path in the buffer buf,
>   which has size bufsiz. readlink() does
>   not append a null byte to buf. It will
>   truncate the contents (to a length of
>   bufsiz characters), in case the buffer
>   is too small to hold all of the
>   contents.

Furthermore, `readlink()` reads the text of the PID, which can be greater than `"9999"`. Using only four bytes to store the PID value in text is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is completely off-base. `sizeof(pid_t)` being 4 does not mean that it takes 4 bytes to store a *decimal string* representing the number. A typical 16-bit pid like 12345 obviously takes 6 bytes to store as a string, and if Linux has been configured to allow more than 32768 processes, it could easily be longer.

The correct size for a buffer to hold a `foo_t` integer type as a decimal string is `3*sizeof(foo_t)+2`. You can do slightly better on the bounds if you care, but I don't mind wasting a few bytes for simplicity (and obvious correctness) in the source.

(Note that I'm assuming 8-bit bytes, which POSIX requires, since pids are a POSIX concept. If you wanted to support larger bytes you'd need to adapt the bound using `CHAR_BIT`.)